# Changing url when opening and closing fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using this code with fancybox 1.3.7. When fancybox opens url changes to the corresponding div (/page#div-id), when it closes it is supposed to go back to /page but the commented function doesn't work. I had to use a temporary value as shown below. How can I fix this?

```
window.onload = function(){
    function showfb(id) {
        if (/^#.*/.test(id)) {
            $(id).show();
            $.fancybox({
                href: id,
                type:'inline',
                position: 'center',
                'transitionIn': 'fade', // elastic, none, ease, fade
                'transitionOut': 'fade',
                onClosed: function(){
                    //$(id).hide();
                    window.location.hash = "_"; // temporary
                }
            });
        }
    }
    showfb(location.hash);
    $('a.profile').click(function(e){
            showfb($(this).attr('href'));
    });
};
```

Comment: Why are you doing `$('a.profile').click(function(e){showfb($(this).attr('href'));});` instead of `$('a.profile').fancybox()`?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the function with the below:

```
window.location.hash = "";
```

Comment: I did that but the # still stays there and despite that the page scrolls up at the very top...

Comment: I'll use  " " (with a space inside) so that the page doesn't scroll up! thnx!